# How to add this class on my button click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

Here, I have done slide code. My when I click on the left and right button.next and previous button.

I want when I click on next button arrow slide show move on the right side with some effect and when I click on previous button arrow is should move left side with some effect.

I used animated fadeInLeft and animated fadeInRight. but i don't know how i add this class ..

I want when i click on left button my class this class (animated fadeInLeft) add  and when i click on previous button my class( animated fadeInRight) should add.

What should i do to add these class when i click on left and right button click.
Here, is my code please review it.

```js
   var divMain = document.getElementById("slide");
    console.log(divMain)

    var align = divMain.getAttribute("type");
    console.log(align)

    if(align == "slideshow") {
        var timeline = document.getElementById('slide');

        timeline.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",'<a class="left animated fadeInLeft color_arrow carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" onclick = "plusDivs(-1)" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>');

        timeline.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',' <a class="right color_arrow  animated fadeInRight carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  onclick = "plusDivs(1)" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>');

        var slideIndex = 2;
        showDivs(slideIndex);

        function plusDivs(sliderItem) {
            showDivs(slideIndex += sliderItem);
        }

        function showDivs(sliderItem) {
            let i;
            let sliderData = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
            
            if (sliderItem > sliderData.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
            if (sliderItem < 1) {slideIndex = sliderData.length}

            for (i = 1; i < sliderData.length; i++) {
                sliderData[i].classList.add('hide')
                sliderData[i].classList.remove('active')  
            }
            sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.remove('hide')
            sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('active') 
        }
    }
```

```css
    
  div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) {
        margin: auto;
        width: 900px;
        z-index: 100;
        border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
        min-height:250px;
        background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 55px;
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
    }

  
    div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) > header {
        font-weight: 600;
        color: cadetblue;
        transform: translate(93px, 32px);
        font-size: 34px;
        font-family: arial;
        position: relative;
    }
    div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) > article {
        transform: translate(87px,39px);
        color: black;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-family: arial;
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
     .active{
        -webkit-animation: fadein 2s
        -moz-animation: fadein 2s; 
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
        -o-animation: fadein 2s; 
        animation: fadein 2s;
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
    .hide{opacity: 0; min-height: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;}
    .hide header, .hide article{display: none;}
    @keyframes fadein {
        0% { opacity: 0 }
        50% { opacity: 0.5 }
        100% {opacity: 1}
    }
```

```html
<div type='slideshow' id='slide'>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title One</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title Two</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title Three</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title Four</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
</div>

These class i want add **animated fadeInLeft and animated fadeInRight**
```

Help will be aprreciated.

Comment: `div` does not have a `type` attribute. Use `data-type` instead.

Comment: you not getting my point.  i want to add class animated fadeInLeft class

Comment: You are not getting my point. Noone is going to even bother to help with  HTML being invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your question... Since there is no `fadeInLeft` class in there.

But, by just changing the initial `slideIndex` and the loop start value of `i`, making it all zero-based, there is an interesting result which probably is what you wish to achieve.

```
var slideIndex = 1;  // Intead of 2
```

And:

```
for (i = 0; ...  // Instead of 1
```

See the difference below::

```js
var divMain = document.getElementById("slide");
    console.log(divMain)

    var align = divMain.getAttribute("type");
    console.log(align)

    if(align == "slideshow") {
        var timeline = document.getElementById('slide');

        timeline.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",'<a class="left animated fadeInLeft color_arrow carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" onclick = "plusDivs(-1)" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>');

        timeline.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',' <a class="right color_arrow  animated fadeInRight carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  onclick = "plusDivs(1)" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>');

        var slideIndex = 1;
        showDivs(slideIndex);

        function plusDivs(sliderItem) {
            showDivs(slideIndex += sliderItem);
        }

        function showDivs(sliderItem) {
            let i;
            let sliderData = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
            
            if (sliderItem > sliderData.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
            if (sliderItem < 1) {slideIndex = sliderData.length}

            for (i = 0; i < sliderData.length; i++) {
                sliderData[i].classList.add('hide')
                sliderData[i].classList.remove('active')  
            }
            sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.remove('hide')
            sliderData[slideIndex-1].classList.add('active') 
        }
    }
```

```css
div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) {
        margin: auto;
        width: 900px;
        z-index: 100;
        border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
        min-height:250px;
        background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 55px;
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
    }

  
    div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) > header {
        font-weight: 600;
        color: cadetblue;
        transform: translate(93px, 32px);
        font-size: 34px;
        font-family: arial;
        position: relative;
    }
    div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) > article {
        transform: translate(87px,39px);
        color: black;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-family: arial;
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
     .active{
        -webkit-animation: fadein 2s
        -moz-animation: fadein 2s; 
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
        -o-animation: fadein 2s; 
        animation: fadein 2s;
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
    .hide{opacity: 0; min-height: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;}
    .hide header, .hide article{display: none;}
    @keyframes fadein {
        0% { opacity: 0 }
        50% { opacity: 0.5 }
        100% {opacity: 1}
    }
```

```html
<div type='slideshow' id='slide'>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title One</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title Two</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title Three</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title Four</header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
</div>

These class i want add **animated fadeInLeft and animated fadeInRight**
```